# Acceptor pooling and load balancing in Erlang?

Tags: performance, erlang, load-balancing, unicorn

From http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#accept-1:

> It is worth noting that the accept call does not have to be issued
>   from the socket owner process. Using version 5.5.3 and higher of the
>   emulator, multiple simultaneous accept calls can be issued from
>   different processes, which allows for a pool of acceptor processes
>   handling incoming connections.

**(Q1)** Does it mean that we can have [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/)-style load balancing in Erlang?

**(Q2)** If so, are there any existing servers or libraries making use of this feature?

**(Q3)** Unicorn works under the assumption that request processing is *fast*. Under the same assumption, is it possible to gain better performance by combining acceptors and workers in Erlang?

For those who are not familiar with Unicorn, it is a traditional UNIX prefork web server. Load balancing between worker processes is done by the OS kernel. All workers share a common set of listener sockets and does non-blocking accept() on them. The kernel will decide which worker process to give a socket to and workers will sleep if there is nothing to accept(). *For a single listener socket, I believe it's the same when the worker processes do blocking accept() and the OS kernel decides the result of the "race".*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also posted this question in the Erlang Questions mailing list.
As pointed out by *Daniel Goertzen*, 
there are acceptor pool libraries in Erlang, such as [ranch](https://github.com/extend/ranch) and [swarm](https://github.com/jeremey/swarm).

- **ranch** works differently from Unicorn in such a way that it only does "accept" in many processes, and then passes the socket to some worker process.
- The way **swarm** works is the same as Unicorn in the sense that
  the acceptor and worker is combined. (Thanks to *Loïc Hoguin* for pointing out)
  But they are a bit different because swarm can accept a new socket in
  parallel with the processing of the accepted socket, while Unicorn
  only accepts after the accepted socket is processed

I prefer the swarm style since it's ideal for both fast and slow
requests, while Unicorn requires fast requests.

> Instead of attempting to be efficient at serving slow clients, unicorn
>   relies on a buffering reverse proxy to efficiently deal with slow
>   clients.
>
> unicorn is not suited for all applications. unicorn is optimized for
>   applications that are CPU/memory/disk intensive and spend little time
>   waiting on external resources (e.g. a database server or external
>   API).
>
> unicorn is highly inefficient for Comet/reverse-HTTP/push applications
>   where the HTTP connection spends a large amount of time idle.

Comment: A guess would be that the ranch approach holds up as well as the swarm approach in practice. Case in point: cowboy uses ranch and cowboy is extremely fast.

Comment: @IGIVECRAPANSWERS Agree. btw, are there any up-to-date benchmarks about cowboy, etc.?

Comment: I don't know. My guess is you need to measure yourself for your workload. For the workloads I have, the problem is elsewhere in the chain long before cowboy even makes its entry as being even slightly a bottleneck.