# Erlang server connection pool

Tags: erlang, json-rpc, erlang-escript

I have a service that is in Erlang. I am trying to connect to the service. However sometimes the connection creation gets timed out. I believe this might be because the service might be busy. This is periodic, on re-executing my program some time later it works well.

I am not sure how connection pool is defined in Erlang. I am trying to look into the same  (unfortunately not much success so far) and would like to change the connection pool size. I am mainly looking into how connection management in done when executing jsonrpc commands. As per documentation only a new connection is created between client and server from any communication. I am trying to identify how to change upper limit for this if any.

Thank-you

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would include the part of the code that listens for and accepts new connections.

Comment: https://github.com/devinus/poolboy  you can see this project

Comment: It is important to know which connection pool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how connection pool is defined in Erlang.

There are some well-known connection pools in Erlang like [ranch](https://github.com/ninenines/ranch) and [swarm](https://github.com/jeremey/swarm), which [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121987/acceptor-pooling-and-load-balancing-in-erlang) you can find a summary of them.

> I am trying to identify how to change upper limit for this if any.

For example in case of ranch you can set the connection pool size this way:

```
AcceptorNumbers = 100,
{ok, _} = ranch:start_listener(
    ListenerRef, 
    AcceptorNumbers,
    Transport, [{port, Port}],
    Protocol, Options
).
```

---

Also you can create your own connection pool on top of OTP behaviours. For example, a pool of Generic Finite State Machines (`gen_fsm`) which holds client connections and are supervised can be as simple as [this tutorial](https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php/Building_a_Non-blocking_TCP_server_using_OTP_principles).